# how to handle divide by zero error in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
cast(CAST(countAta AS float) 
 / CAST(DATEDIFF(day,@searchDate,@EndDate) AS float) as  decimal(16,2)
    )
```

Comment: how about `case when <denominator> = 0 then <0 or null> else <numerator/denominator> end` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always use TRY-CATCH block and use the built-in error handling functions provided by SQL. Also, you can handle it in another way --

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN (CAST(DATEDIFF(Day, @searchDate, @EndDate) AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(16, 2)) = 0
        THEN NULL -- Ideally it should return NULL but you can change it as per your requirement
    ELSE CAST(CAST(Counter AS FLOAT) / CAST(DATEDIFF(Day, @searchDate, @EndDate) AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(16, 2))
    END
```

Comment: where should place alias name Productivity like this:::cast(CAST(countAta AS float) / CAST(DATEDIFF(day,@searchDate,@EndDate)AS float) as  decimal(16,2)) as Productivity

Comment: At the very end of the query.
    END as Productivity

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid such situations by setting the following parameters before your query and it should work just fine.

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF 
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
```

This would return a `NULL` when you do something like this: `123 / 0`

The important point is to set these properties back `ON` once you are done with such operations. This particularly helps when you have complex queries in your Stored procedure and you don't want to end up writing more and more `CASE` statements to handle such a situation.

Comment: one up vote from me since this is useful and I just learned about these features now.

Comment: Literally saved me as this was temporary requirement. Thanks!

Comment: This saved me a ton of time as I would've needed to go through 5000 lines of code to update multiple case statements

Answer (score 0):

The best way is `NULLIF()` . . . but you can't turn the value back into a `0`:

```
select CAST(CAST(countAta AS float) /
            NULLIF(DATEDIFF(day, @searchDate, @EndDate), 0
                  ) as  decimal(16, 2)
           )
```

This returns `NULL` if the denominator is 0.  Note that you don't have to cast to a float twice.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [NULLIF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql) to avoid devided by zero error.
It returns NULL when denominator equals 0

```
CAST(countAta AS decimal(16,2)) /ISNULL(NULLIF(DATEDIFF(day,@searchDate,@EndDate),0), 1)
```

Or use `CASE WHEN`

```
CAST(countAta AS decimal(16,2)) /
CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(day,@searchDate,@EndDate) = 0 THEN 1 
     ELSE DATEDIFF(day,@searchDate,@EndDate) 
END
```

Comment: i want 1 when datadiff is zero

Comment: @vishu it's easy by using `ISNULL`. And i don't see this requirement in your question...